# Jquery Loop stops after 2nd element

Tags: jquery, loops

I am trying to check to see if one of these radio boxes is checked and, if it is, to uncheck it and check the next in line.

I'd like to repeat this process every 4 seconds.

```
<section class="cr-container">
<input id="select-img-1" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-1 radio-set" checked/>
<input id="select-img-2" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-2 radio-set" />
<input id="select-img-3" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-3 radio-set" />
<input id="select-img-4" name="radio-set-1" type="radio" class="cr-selector-img-4 radio-set" />
</section>
```

i tried something like this but it's not working

```
$(".cr-container input").each(function(){
    setTimeout( function () {
        requestFunction(data, function(status){
            if ( status == 'OK' ) { 
                if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
                    $(this).next().prop('checked', true);
                }
            }
        });
    }, indexInArray * 400);
});
```

Comment: possible scope problem. you have a function within a function within a function.  what do you expect `this` to refer to? can you set up a jsfiddle for testing please

Comment: (indexInArray * 400) IS NOT 4 seconds.

Comment: What is request function? some ajax call?

Comment: Forget about the jquery i just posted , it seems to be so wrong , can u please give me a code which i can do what i want with it

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/2et3m/

Comment: yes exactly except it stops at fourth radio box , can't it be repetitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you were looking for:

Here is the **jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/BTuaS/

```
setInterval(repeatProcess, 4000);

function repeatProcess() {
    $(".cr-container input").first().prop('checked', true);
    $(".cr-container input").each(function(i){
        var self = $(this);
        setTimeout( function () {
            requestFunction("", function(status){
                if ( status == 'OK' ) { 
                    if (self.prop('checked')) {
                        self.next().prop('checked', true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }, (i + 1) * 1000);
    });
}

function requestFunction(data, status){
    status('OK');
}
```

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @b_dubb, the problem is the in scope since $(this) after two callbacks is no longer the element you wanted.

Try something like that:

```
$(".cr-container input").each(function(){
    self = this
    setTimeout( function () {
        requestFunction(data, function(status){
            if ( status == 'OK' ) { 
                if ($(self).attr('checked')) {
                    $(self).prop('checked', false); //You wanted to uncheck current element, didn't you?
                    $(self).next().prop('checked', true);
                }
            }
        });
    }, indexInArray * 400);
});
```

Regarding the 4 sec interval, indexInArray * 400 does not do what you want. Do you want to cheack all elements every 4 secs of do you want to check one element each 4 secs?

BTW a console.log($(this)) might have helped you

**EDIT**

Since elementcs are radio buttons and not checkboxes there's no need to uncheck the current element, so you can easily omit the line:

```
$(self).prop('checked', false); //You wanted to uncheck current element, didn't you?
```

Which would be needed only if the elements were check boxes (multiple select allowed)